# maven-war-plugin include subdirectories

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

I'm having an issue where I need to include some folders in my Maven generated WAR using the maven-war-plugin but it is only including the files in the directory and not the sub-directories as well. This is how I have configured the war-plugin within the pom.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
             <webXml>WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>  
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>icons</directory>
                        <targetPath>icons</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>data</directory>
                        <targetPath>data</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

This generates the folder data in the war root like so:

```
data
-> file1.txt
```

but the source folder contains subdirectories which I would like copied as well like so.

```
data
->english
    --> english.txt
-> file1.txt
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your configuration should do what you expect because it is recursive by default. Ensure `english` exists and is readable. Also check the log and other configurations that may be affecting this.

Comment: Thanks, checked the folders and the subdirectories are actually empty - adding a file to one of the empty subdirectories created the folder. I didn't realise that the folders had to have contents for the structure to be created! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) to add empty folders if you say explicitly by [using the appropriate configuration parameter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#includeEmptyDirectories):

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <includeEmptyDirectories>true</includeEmptyDirectories>
          ..
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```